# Total angular momentum (torque) of multiple forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque, rotational-kinematics

If multiple forces act on a single body, we know that if the total angular momentum is null the body does not rotate. How does the principle take into account that I can take any point in space as the one to be used to calculate the different momentum and so the result can be different with different choices of these points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque#Net_force_versus_torque):

> *When the net force on the system is zero, the torque measured from any point in space is the same.* For example, the torque on a current-carrying loop in a uniform magnetic field is the same regardless of the point of reference. If the net force $\mathbf {F}$ is not zero, and $\tau_1$ is the torque measured from $\mathbf {r}_{1}$, then the torque measured from $\mathbf {r}_{2}$ is
> ${\boldsymbol {\tau }}_{2}={\boldsymbol {\tau }}_{1}+(\mathbf {r}_{1}-\mathbf {r}_{2})\times \mathbf {F}$

(emphasis is mine)

The key here is that the statement is true for the case when the total force is zero. Suppose we have several forces, producing zero net torque:
$$
\boldsymbol{\tau}_{total}=\sum_i\mathbf{r}_i\times\mathbf{F}_i=0
$$
if we now calculate the torques in respect to a different point, all the position vectors changes as $\mathbf{r}_i\rightarrow \mathbf{r}_i'=\mathbf{r}_i+\mathbf{R}$, and we have the total torque as

$$ \begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\tau}_{total}' &= \sum_i\mathbf{r}_i'\times\mathbf{F}_i  \\
&= \sum_i\left(\mathbf{r}_i+\mathbf{R}\right)\times\mathbf{F}_i \\
&= \left(\sum_i\mathbf{r}_i\times\mathbf{F}_i \right) + \left( \mathbf{R}\times\sum_i\mathbf{F}_i  \right) \\
&= \boldsymbol{\tau}_{total} + \mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{F}_{total} \\
&=0 \\
 \end{align} $$

since the total force is zero.

Comment: "When the net force on the system is zero" this was exactely what I needed. Thanks